# C# short-circuiting weirdness

Tags: c#

Given a = null
Shouldn't this not throw an exception?

```
if(a != null && ((string)a).ToLower()=="boo"){
  ... operation
}
```

Due to lazy evaluation the second statement should never be called so this ((string)a).ToLower() shouldn't be throwing an exception right ?

UPDATE

```
IOrderedEnumerable<SPListItem> Items = sourceList.GetItems("ProjectID", "Title", "ProjectName", "Featured", "Size", "Description")
    .Cast<SPListItem>().AsEnumerable().OrderBy((i => rnd.Next()));

SPListItemCollection randProjImages = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("Random Projects Images").GetItems();
var randomImgNrs = Enumerable.Range(0, randProjImages.Count).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

Dictionary<string, string> projectImages = new Dictionary<string,string>();
IEnumerable<SPListItem> projImages = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("Assigned Projects Images").
    GetItems().Cast<SPListItem>().AsEnumerable();
foreach (SPListItem it in projImages) projectImages.Add((string)it["ProjectID"], (string)it["ServerUrl"]);

int qCount = 0;
foreach (SPListItem item in Items) {
    if (item["Size"] != null && item["Featured"]!=null &&
            ((string)item["Size"]).ToLower() == "big" || ((string)item["Featured"]).ToLower() == "yes") {
        dataItems.Add(new Project(item["ProjectID"].ToString(), (string)item["Title"],
            "/sites/Galileo/SitePages/" + Utils.getCurrentLang().ToLower() + "/Projects.aspx#id=pwp" + item["ProjectID"],
            projectImages[(string)item["ProjectID"]],
            Utils.truncateString(item.Fields["Description"].GetFieldValueAsText(item["Description"]), 175), "project"));
    }else{
```

Replacing the foreach with this:

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in Items) {
            var k = item["Size"];
            if (item["Size"] != null && item["Featured"]!=null &&
                    ((string)item["Size"]).ToLower() == "big" || ((string)item["Featured"]).ToLower() == "yes") {
                dataItems.Add(new Project(item["ProjectID"].ToString(), (string)item["Title"],
                    "/sites/Galileo/SitePages/" + Utils.getCurrentLang().ToLower() + "/Projects.aspx#id=pwp" + item["ProjectID"],
                    projectImages[(string)item["ProjectID"]],
                    Utils.truncateString(item.Fields["Description"].GetFieldValueAsText(item["Description"]), 175), "project"));
            }else{
```

And breaking just before the if statement in the debugger, k == null

Comment: Are you sure `a` is null?  Is it a nullable type?

Comment: shouldn't be an exception here because of a=null

Comment: a is not null but not a string maybe.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: if a is string, use !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) instead of a != null

Comment: why do you need to cast 'a' to a string?  what type is it?  a var? give a little more context

Comment: @Anton: `var` is only syntactic sugar. The compiler infers the correct type. But you're correct. More information on `a` and the context is needed.

Comment: this question is ridiculous. too bad I can't vote it down

Comment: The Exception is System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to get more details after I quickly changed it to be: string a = a!=null ? a : ""; if(a != "boo") ...
So now I'm just going back to it to get more info from the initial issue

Comment: @haknick: Show us the REAL code.

Comment: When in a Sharepoint item list a record is not filled then the value in this case item["Featured"] == null

Comment: Here's the full log: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PeopleWebPart
  StackTrace:
       at PeopleWebPart.Gateway.Data.addProjects()
       at PeopleWebPart.Gateway.Data.getAll()
       at PeopleWebPart.Gateway.Gateway.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeStaticWebPartContainer.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at

Comment: I wish ppl in Sharepoint.Stackexchange.com would be as fast giving downvotes as in here :) At least there's some attention

Comment: access item using index instead of by name, the item["Size"] or item["Featured"] can give you the exception

Comment: I can't rely on the index as the users in the system can move columns around but are instructed to always have the designed names
And there's no exception on item, it's just 'item["Size"] evaluates to null

Comment: breaking just before the for loop? why not inside the loop?

Comment: because might be that the item you're fetching is null, so you can't access it

Comment: Ahh my bad, I meant, just before the if statement. Fixed now

Comment: looks like you have 1 bracket missing at the end of the if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if (item["Size"] != null && item["Featured"]!=null &&
>               ((string)item["Size"]).ToLower() == "big" || ((string)item["Featured"]).ToLower() == "yes")

it goes to the ((string)item["Featured"]).ToLower() == "yes")

Comment: WOW ... what a stupid miss
That's why coding for more than 15 hours straight is not good

Answer (score 2):

No exception:

```
string a = null;
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")

string a = "";
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")

string a = "boo";
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")
```

this is as it should be (though the casting is unnecessary).

Does not compile:

```
T a = new T();
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")

T? a = null;
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")

T? a = new T();
if (a != null && ((string) a).ToLower() == "boo")
```

where `T` is any type other than `string` due to casting from `T` to `string`.
The real question is: Why do think it throws an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the second argument of && is not evaluated if the first argument is false (`a` is `null`). So the code cannot throw a NullReferenceException. However, if `a` is not `null` but an object that cannot be cast to `string`, the code can throw an InvalidCastException.

Note that the best practice for comparing strings in a case-insensitive way is to use the [String.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx):

```
if (String.Equals(a, "foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // ... operation
}
```

Since the method is static, no null-check is needed.

Comment: The exception is `NullReferenceException` so obviously the code provided by OP is not the real code.

Comment: I know I can do this, but I was very curious to know why the above happened ?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, this will not throw an exception. Since your expression is `AND`, evaluating only the first part is enough to know that it will never evaluate to true, so the second part is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Correct! (except that it's not called lazy evaluation)

If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346.aspx